# Can't access downloaded DLC in Lego Batman 3

Tags: xbox-360, lego-batman-3

I've downloaded the "Heroines and Villainesses" DLC for Lego Batman 3: Beyond Gotham on my Xbox 360 but I cannot seem to find a way to access it.

None of the characters from the pack (including Raven and Starfire) appear on the character choice screen. Is this a bug, or is there something I need to do?